# How to take Screenshot of Camera preview for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, snapshot

I'm working on Augmented Reality app, so I add content to camera preview and I need to take screenshot/snapshot for this content with the camera preview (as a background for this content).

I tried a lot of ways but all create a Black background under content (camera preview is black).

Is there any way to do that ?

I'm working on iOS 9.1 and Xcode 7.1 - Objective-C

Thank you,

Comment: Did you mean that taking photos/videos without any user interaction in camera preview page?

Comment: No, I will add a feature to enable User to take a screenshot by himself of whole content (which is disabled on camera preview) by clicking on button, this image show content correctly but camera appears as a black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample solved my problem by openGL.[Screenshots](https://github.com/cocoacoderorg/Screenshots)